# count different data with same name in column as 1 count sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

sorry i want to ask about this i already try but still cant get it
ok i have a table like this

```
tblcount
-----------------------
no_req  no_order    no_grn   
R001    D001        G001
R001            
R001    D001        G001
R002    D002        
R002    D002        G002
R003    D001        G001
R004    D003        G002
R004    D003        G002
R005    D003     
R005    D003
R006    D004        G002
R006    D005        G003
R006    D007
R007    D007        G005
R007    D008        G006
```

I want to count with criteria like this.
example, from table above there is 3 data of R001 from no_req but only 2 from no_order and no_grn so it doesnt count. it will only count the complete data. something like this:

1. no_req R001 with 3 data but no_order and no_grn only 2 = it doesnt count
2. no_req R002 with 2 data no order with 2 data but no_grn only 1 = it doesnt count
3. no_req R003 with 1 data no_order and no_grn with 1 data = it count 1
4. no_req R004 with 2 data no_order and no_grn with 2 data = it count 1
5. no_req R005 with 2 data no_order with 2 data, no_grn 0 = it doesnt count
6. no_req R006 with 3 data no_order with 3 data, no_grn 2 data = it doesnt count
7. no_req R007 with 2 data no_order and no_grn with 2 data = it count 1

so from data above I can get count result = 3
what should I do so I can get that count result = 3 from table above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
  SELECT no_req  
  FROM tblcount
  GROUP BY no_req 
  HAVING COUNT(*) = COUNT(CASE WHEN no_order <> '' THEN no_order END) AND 
         COUNT(*) = COUNT(CASE WHEN no_grn <> '' THEN no_grn END)) AS t
```

The inner query selects any `no_req` groups that statisfy the conditions. The outer query just counts the numbers of these groups.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/58abd/1)

Comment: i already try in my sql server but what i got is 7 
is it because the content from my insert is ' '  instead NULL ??

INSERT INTO tblcount
    (`no_req`, `no_order`, `no_grn`)
VALUES
    ('R001', 'D001', 'G001'),
    ('R001', ' ', ' '),

Comment: @AndrianoCrs Glad I was able to help. Please mark this, or any other, answer as accepted if it helped you solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Simplifying @GiorgosBetsos logig:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
 (
  SELECT no_req  
  FROM tblcount
  GROUP BY no_req 
  HAVING -- check if both columns always contain data 
     COUNT(CASE WHEN no_order = '' OR no_grn = '' THEN 1 END) = 0
 ) AS t
```

Comment: Thanks Dieter,  one up !